# Creating a Route 53 pointing to AWS ApiGateway

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53, amazon-gateway

Well, I have a `AWS::ApiGateway::RestApi` resource that generates always a url like this:  `https://{GATEWAYID}.execute-api.{REGION}.amazonaws.com/{STAGE}`

So, I created I `CNAME in Route 53`, with the following characteristics:

```
  CnameRoute53Api:
    Type: AWS::Route53::RecordSet
    Properties:
      HostedZoneId: !Ref MyHostedZone
      Name: api.privatedomain
      Type: CNAME
      TTL: 300
      ResourceRecords:
        - !Sub ${GatewayId}.execute-api.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com
    DependsOn: MyHostedZone
```

As you can see I'm creating a CNAME inside my `private hostedzone` pointing to my gateway. Now I'm trying to make a CURL inside a EC2 in this account:

```
curl -v https://api.privatedomain
```

And I got the following error:

```
url: (51) SSL: no alternative certificate subject name matches target host name 'api.privatedomain'
```

I understand that SSL certificate is not prepared to accept request from "api.privatedomain". Is there anyway to fix it ? I don't want to buy a custom domain to expose my api to internet, this api will be accessible only inside this account.

Comment: You can use AWS Certificate Manager.

Comment: Can you give more information about it ? ACM should be used in ROUTE 53 ou AWS GAteway ? And how?

Comment: Create a cert for your private domain name. Associate it with your API Gateway. Should be fairly easy.

Comment: This may help: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-custom-domains.html

Comment: I just can create ACM for public domain, I tried create with domain "api.privatedomain" and got error: "ACM just for public domain"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you already observed, you can't do this due to SSL issues. If you don't want to use AWS provided API default domain, you have to buy **your own public domain** for which you can get free, public SSL certificate using ACM.

But anyway, if you don't want to have public API, why not create [private API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-private-apis.html). At the moment, your private zone will resolve to public API over the internet. Thus its rather counter productive to use private zone for that.

The use of private API, unlike public API, ensures that entire traffic between your instance and the API does not happen over the internet.

Comment: So, if I understand the only way is to use private dns generates by aws amazon gateway, something like execute-api.region, Right?

Comment: @RonaldoLanhellas I'm not sure if this is the only way, but I think its most logical way. You have private HZ for private API. Otherwise, keep API public and get normal domain for it.

Comment: @RonaldoLanhellas Also with curl, you can ignore the warring about ssl using `-k` flag. You can try with that `curl -v -k https://api.privatedomain`

Comment: When you say "you have private HZ for private API", not really, because I can't point my HZ to aws gateway because SSL problem.

Comment: @RonaldoLanhellas You can point. Route53 does not worry about ssl. Its only your applications that check it, such as `curl`. Try `curl -v -k https://api.privatedomain`.

Comment: I agree, but my net core application that need calls this api through route 53 will crash with ssl problem. Sure that I can configure to ignore the problem but I really think this is not a good option, like use curl -k

Comment: @RonaldoLanhellas I verified, with private API you will get same SSL errors. Using `curl -k` will ignore them, but API will return forbidden access. And you can't setup private custom domain for the api, at least I haven't found a way for that.

Comment: @RonaldoLanhellas No problem. For now it seems that you have to stick with aws provided dns for private api, or get  your own domain for public API. But public domain can't be for your private HZ. It must be normal public domain.

Comment: Ok, thanks again Marcin, I will following using private dns provided by aws